# 301 redirect issue with IIS6.0 and dot net 4.0

Tags: iis-6

I have a website built in dot net 4.0 using CMS (sitefinity4.0). This site is hosted on IIS6.0 I was trying URL Canonicalization where i need mysite.com/innerpages.aspx to redirect www.mysite.com/innerpages.aspx When I do a 302 redirection for mysite.com it works fine and the pages get redirected to www.mysite.com/innerpage.aspx but when i attempt to do 301 redirects the its shows 404 error for eurl.axd/.

The same setup on staging(with same app and IIS setting)  works fine for 301 and 302 redirects.

While looking for solution I come across articles suggesting to disable ASP.NET v4.0 Extensionless URL feature on IIS 6.0 -  [Default.aspx page won't load on IIS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315861/default-aspx-page-wont-load-on-iis-6)

But I have checked the setting on staging and found that  it is not disabled on staging. hence I am not sure if this will work.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "But I have checked the setting on staging and found that it is not disabled on staging." If it is NOT disabled, then you're going to get the extensionless URL tacked on. What is basically happening is that in a redirect the process doesn't realize the internally tacked on "eurl.axd/GUID" isn't part of the actual URL, so it gets left on (instead of stripped off). Now if you're purposely trying to use extensionless URLs on your site and a redirect, well then hopefully someone else can come in here an help.

However, if you aren't using extensionless URLs, then you need to disable it. You do that by altering a registry key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET\4.0.30319.0\EnableExtensionlessUrls = 0`

And you have to restart IIS after changing that registry entry. If you don't have that registry entry, then IIS treats it as if it were "on" (EnableExtensionlessUrls = 1). So you have to explicitly add it to get rid of it.

NOTE: if you're running 64-bit the registry key you're looking for is in a different place:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\ASP.NET\v4.0.30319.0\EnableExtensionlessUrls = 0`